# How to get mouse button controls?

Tags: python, windows, pygame, mouse, python-2.x

I trying to work out how to get the mouse button controls.

I tried looking in `pygame` docs but it doesn't say; it just returns the state of the mouse. I do understand this but I don't know how to use that info to control the buttons on the mouse.

I have made a game where you could shoot bullets. Whenever you place the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` command in my python script and you try clicking the buttons on the mouse, the right and the left shoots bullets. How can I make it so that only the left mouse button only shoots bullets while the right button does something else?

Also, can you add automatic on the mouse? Instead of clicking the mouse button several times, whenever the left or the right mouse button is pressed the bullet shoots automatically instead of clicking on the button several times.

It starts to get annoying when you're playing a game. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` ([link to docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed)) to get a

> sequence of booleans representing the state of all the mouse buttons. A `True` value means the mouse is currently being pressed at the time of the call.

As far as "automatic" fire goes, each time round your `pygame.event` loop you can check if the button is still pressed and fire another bullet.